# Why couldn't the Murtlap Essence be returned to the Bowl?

Tags: harry-potter

In the Order of the Phoenix, when Harry goes into a rage and breaks the bowl of Murtlap Essence, He repaired the bowl but he also thought there was no returning of The Essence back:

> "Reparo", and the bowl repaired instantly. But there was no returning of the Essence and Harry wished he hadn't broke it...

But why so? Couldn't there be a simple charm to refill (and I don't mean the Transfiguration kind of refill but simply filling the spilled liquid back into the Bowl)? Or at least Hermione must have known it (it should have been a relatively simple charm for a 5th year anyway).

Comment: "Couldn't there be...?" Well, apparently not, or at least not that was known to Harry. I guess nobody has discovered/invented a spell to separate liquid from carpet and all the other mess that would litter the floor of the Gryffindor common room.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist there must have been some spell to selectively bring out the liquid from a mess...

Comment: Why **must** there have been such a spell? One isn't ever mentioned in canon as far as I know. Even if there was, why would Harry - or even Hermione - know about it? They didn't seem to teach general housework spells at Hogwarts.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist What about the dragonblood at Slughorn's place? Wasn't that put back into its vial?

Comment: @calccrypto but he also said too much dust...

Comment: @prakharlondhe I don't have the time to look it up but Ron performs *Tergeo* on a grimy hanky to clean it off before handing it to Hermione in *Deathly Hallows*. That would presumably help with cleaning the carpet but not with getting the Murtlap essence back. The House Elves must've had methods for cleaning stubborn stains as part of their cleaning duties.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears that someone as skilled as Slughorn, couldn't retain purity after something is spilled/poured out.

> "On the walls? Dragon" shouted the wizard called Horace, ... "Yes,
>   dragon," repeated the wizard conversationally. "My last bottle, and
>   prices are sky-high at the moment. Still, it might be reusable."
>
> He stumped over to a small crystal bottle standing on top of a
>   sideboard and held it up to the light, examining the thick fluid
>   within.  "Hmm. Bit Dusty."

To note Dumbledore and Slughorn are waving their wands and non-verbally cleaning the room, magic that may or may not be far beyond what Harry can do in year 6, and spilling the Murtlap Essence was in year 5.

Comment: well OK then... I nearly figured it out (as mentioned in the comment).. thanks :).. could you please also take a look at my another question which asks "why a wizard can't turn to muggle world to earn some money"... It hasn't having any good acceptable answer yet...